# What Happened to the Hole Blown in the Klingon Vessel?

Tags: star-trek

When the crew is attempting time travel on Star Trek IV a hole is blown in the side of the ship next to Uhura. Number one why didn't she get sucked close to it? But my real question is at the end of the movie when they're traveling back to their present time the hole is gone. Did Scotty patch it up?

Comment: Option 1: yes. Option 2: a plot hole in Star Trek. Either way, no big deal.

Comment: Doesn't Star Trek pre-Abrams have instant forcefields and structural integrity fields to protect against hull breaches? I only seem to recall dramatic hull depressurisation being a thing on the Kelvin in Abrams' movie

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from this wider shot, the thing that explodes (and blows glass into the side of her face) appears to be **a video monitor** rather than an external window. As such there would be no decompression effects and no need to repair the outside of the ship.

[image]